# put stack trace to string variable

Tags: go

Is it possible to put stack trace like this ...

```
goroutine 20 [running]:
runtime.panic(0x3a2820, 0xc2081ad4b0)
    /usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime/panic.c:279 +0xf5
testing.func·006()
    /usr/local/go/src/pkg/testing/testing.go:416 +0x176
runtime.panic(0x3a2820, 0xc2081ad4b0)
    /usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime/panic.c:248 +0x18d
my.Test(0x3a2820, 0xc2081acf20, 0x3a2820, 0xc2081acf30, 0xc208056000)
    /Users/usr/golang/src/my/testing.go:67 +0x572
```

... in string variable for reformating it and cut off redundunt information for me.

This pseudo code would be like this:

```
package main

import (
    "runtime"
)

func main() {
    var stackStr string
    stackStr = runtime.GetStackFromHere()
}
```

I tried `panic("give me stack trace from here")` but it prints stack trace not in `var string` but only to console.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [runtime.Stack](http://godoc.org/runtime#Stack) function to get the stack trace:

```
b := make([]byte, 2048) // adjust buffer size to be larger than expected stack
n := runtime.Stack(b, false)
s := string(b[:n])
```

An alternative approach is to call [runtime.Caller](http://godoc.org/runtime#Caller) in a loop and format the stack trace to a buffer.